# Сайт выводит ошибку при авторизации парсером

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, bs4

Стоит задача: авторизоваться перейти на вкладку профиль и вывести все значения.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import fake_useragent
```

создание сессии

```
session = requests.Session()  # записывает куки и можно начинать с того места где закончил
```

фейк user-agent для маскировки парсера

```
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random

header = {'user-agent': user}
# http://forum.ru-board.com/misc.cgi - url post запроса
```

ссылка на авторизацию

```
link = "http://forum.ru-board.com/misc.cgi?action=login"

datas = {
    "inmembername": u"<login>",
    "inpassword": u"<password>",
}
```

авторизация на сайте

```
response = session.post(link, data=datas, headers=header).text  # data=данные, 
#headers=заголовки
print(response)
```

переход в профиль

```
profile_info = "http://forum.ru-board.com/profile.cgi"
profile_response = session.get(profile_info).text

print(profile_response)
```

Output:

```
<title>Ошибка :: Компьютерный форум Ru.Board</title>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Ru-Board" href="http://rss.ru- 
board.com/rss.cgi" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" alink="#333333" vlink="#333333" link="#333333" topmargin="2" 
leftmargin="0">
<table cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1 border=0 width="95%" align="center" bgcolor="#999999">
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td valign=top align=left class=tit><a href="board.cgi"><b>Компьютерный 
форум Ru.Board</b></a> &raquo; Ошибка</td></tr></table>
<br><table cellpadding=4 cellspacing=1 border=0 width=95% bgcolor=#999999 align=center>
<tr><td bgcolor=#EEEEEE valign=middle align=center class=tit><b>Главное</b></td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor=#FFFFFF valign=middle class=dats>
<br><ol  type=square>
<li><b>Пожалуйста, только корректным способом входите в скрипт</b>
</ol><b>Возможные причины:</b>
<ol type=square>
```

вот неправильный пароль и т.д.

```
<li>Неправильный пароль
<li>Неправильное имя пользователя
<li><a href="legal.cgi">Незарегистрированный</a> Пользователь
</ol><br><center><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)"> << Вернуться назад</a>
</center></tr></td></table><br><center><br><a class="small" href="http://forum.ru- 
board.com/infoads.cgi">Реклама на форуме Ru.Board.</a></center><br><table width=80% 
align=center cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0><tr><td align=center valign=middle 
class=small>Powered by <a href="http://www.ikonboard.com">Ikonboard "v2.1.7b"</a> &copy; 2000 
Ikonboard.com<br>Modified by Ru.Board<br>&copy; Ru.Board 2000-2020<br/><br/>BitCoin: <a 
href="bitcoin:1NGG1chHtUvrtEqjeerQCKDMUi6S6CG4iC">1NGG1chHtUvrtEqjeerQCKDMUi6S6CG4iC</a></td> 
</tr></table>
```

Вопрос:
Как нормально авторизоваться, чтобы не выводило ошибку и можно было продолжить парсинг?

Если что-то не понятно по коду, пишите в комментарии

Answer (score 0):

3 дня искал - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
datas = {
"action":"dologin"### на картинке написано почему
"inmembername": "логин",
"inpassword": "пароль"
}
```